# Akka http , при передаче файла xlsx как Array[bytes] получаю папку

Tags: apache-poi, akka-http, akka

Не так давно работаю с `akka http`, столкнулся с проблемой:
имеется `rout`, который возвращает файл с отчетом определенного формата.
При возврате `xlsx` файла, юзер получает папку, которую можно переименовать в `report.xlsx` и получим нормальный рабочий `excel` файл.

Очень нужна помощь, может кто то сталкивался с такой проблемой.

```
       path("api" / "reports" / "downloadReport") {
        gget {
          parameters('format, 'jobId.as[Long]) { (format, jobId) =>
            uncacheReport(jobId) match {
              case None => complete(ResourceNotFound)
              case Some(report) if format == "excel" =>
                encodeResponse {
                  val reportHtml: String = representerSupport.represent(report, HTMLFormat.Excel)(user.settings.interfaceSettings)
                  complete(HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`), ByteString(reportwriter bytes reportHtml)))
                }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: Получить файл из папки переименованием это сильное шаманство, однако

Comment: Хотя я в такое не верю, а верю что автор не понимает разницы между папкой и zip-архивом. А xlsx-файл технически как раз таки zip-архив и вся «магия» только в имени и структуре архива.

Comment: @AlexeyTen был бы признателен за помощь в решении проблемы

Comment: добавление заголовка "Content-Disposition" решило проблему

Answer (score 0):

добавление заголовка "Content-Disposition" решило проблему

```
encodeResponse {
  val reportHtml: String = representerSupport.represent(report, HTMLFormat.Excel)(user.settings.interfaceSettings)
  val header = RawHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=report.xlsx")
  respondWithHeader(header) {
    complete(HttpEntity(ContentType(MediaTypes.`application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet`), reportwriter bytes reportHtml))
  }
}
```